# Dell RAID1 Pred Fail Yes

Tags: raid1, failed

I have a server with RAID 1 configured that was running too slow.. some applications does not even run.

I entered SAS Config. Utility and I checked that RAID 1 was in status 'not synced', but I was able to sync it.

Today, both disks have already the same space, but the secondary drive has Pred Fail Status = Yes, and computer still remains in the same status..

I tried to run 'Dell Diagnostic Tool' but I can't install the downloaded exe file, I double click and nothing happens..

I tried to run OpenManage Server Administrator (OMSA) (already installed before), but also none window opens..

I tried also run Dell SAS Raid Storage Manager (already installed), window opens, but no server is displayed

I want to bring the second drive offline in order to remove and replace it..

I wonder if I just can remove the drive physically without bring it offline previously without that causing problems..

I'm also getting a strange error 'Event Notification Application' » 'Unable to register with Framework, program will now exit' » I already tried re install framework (4.5) but computer freezes and nothing happens..

Glad for any help on this.

Comment: You can just pull the drive and put in a new one.

Comment: I don't have a new one to replace. If I just remove it without replace by another, will computer run? Will I just need to rebuid? How do I know which physical disk is the secondary one? Thanks!

Comment: Usually the drives are numbered and tell you which slot it's in. I highly advise you do *not* run the machine with a degraded RAID. Rebuild it with a new disk. Or pray you have backups if the other drive goes.

Comment: OK, thanks! If I replace the disk, I need also to replace the 'bad' disk.. or it could end bad.. Another question, how do I now which type of RAID do I have, software raid or hardware? If software raid, it could end bad also if I remove the 'bad' disk..

Comment: If you have to boot into an OS to see RAID, it's software. Do you have a RAID controller?

Comment: When computer restarts, when starting, I click control+c and I get an image similar to this one [link](http://i.gzn.jp/img/2012/09/08/dell-hdd-replacement/GIG_1483.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's hardware RAID for sure. "Pred Fail" means it failed a SMART test which is a good indication the disk is about to die. Order a replacement disk and replace it ASAP. Your array will still work while degraded but it'll be slow *and* you risk your data since if the primary drive goes before rebuild finishes your data is gone forever.

Comment: Thanks! I removed the secondary disk, for now I just want to remove the RAID1 and keep one disk) No I get the status degraded and the secondary disk is with status missing. I read that I need to rebuild the virtual array, but I can't find that option anywhere. How do I remove he RAID1?

Comment: You can't without wiping the disk.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your comment.. Can I have a RAID 1 with just one disk? How do I remove the RAID 1? Can I just 'delete array'? Thanks.

Comment: Unless you want to lose all of your data then I suggest that you get a replacement drive and insert it into the server. The RAID controller will `rebuild` the virtual disk for you. You're fumbling around with this due to your lack of experience and understanding and you're putting your server and data at risk as a result.

Comment: I've just replaced the disk. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, you need to replace the disk reporting a SMART failure (predictive failure) ASAP. If you're not able to do this and want to move to a "non-RAID" setup, you can use the "reconfigure" task on the virtual disk from OMSA (if you're able to get it running) to convert the virtual disk's RAID type to 0. In this setup, the "non-RAID" disk would still be managed as a virtual disk by the controller, but the data would no longer be striped across multiple drives.

By the sound of things though, you may be stuck with reinstalling your operating system to get things running properly. Avoiding this would take some serious intervention from technical support, whether that be in-warranty support or paid-for support (you do have the option to pay Dell for a one-time assist if your warranty is expired).

Good luck!

Comment: I've just replaced the disk. Thanks for your answer!